# Reflexivity and homeomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $ X_{1}, X_{2} $ standard spaces where one of them is reflective. If there is a linear homeomorphism between these spaces, that is, a bijective linear operator $T: X_{1} \to X_{2} $ continuous with continuous inverse, then the other space is also reflective.

Comment: This question fits a pattern which may be exemplified by this: suppose you have a twin sister which is identical to yourself in all respects.  Suppose also that you love chocolate.  Does your sister like chocolate too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scheme of proof: If $T:X_1\to X_2$ is an isomorphism, and $J:X_1\to X_1^{**}$, $x\mapsto x^{**}$, is an isomorphism, then let $S:X_1^{**}\to X_2^{**}$ be the isomorphism induced by $T$. Then $$SJT^{-1}:X_2\to X_1\to X_1^{**}\to X_2^{**}$$ is the required isomorphism.